# .NET CF Don't trigger button-click on return

Tags: c#, .net, button, onclick, compact-framework

I have a c# .net cf 3.5 application on windows mobile 6.5

On a form there are several buttons with `onclick-events`.

How do I prevent the events from triggering, if they were sent by a return (on the software **or** hardware-keyboard) an not a "real" click?

Can I find out, which *action* sent the click-event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to prevent the Enter button to trigger Click.

- Make a dummy/hidden button as the AcceptButton of the form. That way
  any Enter press would trigger that button instead.
- Change the event handler to trigger on MouseUp or MouseDown instead
- Subscribe to GotFocus event and set it to Focus on other control
  instead. That way it won't receive Enter event